# CSS Div link text underline hover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have a simple div like this...

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="promo-box promo-1">
    <div class="promo-content">
     <h2>Heading here</h2>
     <p>Text content here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

...which allows me to change background color on div hover.
Works great, but as a result, I get the text inside the link showing an underline on hover.
I have tried several ways to target the h2 and p, but still can't get rid of the text-decoration on hover.

Any ideas on what html element i need to target to apply text-decoration: none ?

CSS here...

```
.promo-box
{
text-align:center;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
min-height:240px;
}
h2
{
font-family:Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
color:#FFF;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.promo-box p
{
font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
color:#FFF;
font-size:16px;
line-height:16px;
}
.promo-1
{
background-color:#125595;
}
div.promo-1:hover;
}
```

Comment: Showing your existing CSS would be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to apply text-decoration to the link not  to `h2` or `p` like this:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

you can't apply a style `text-decoration:none` to element inside a line.
You can assign a class to the link if yu don't wamt to apply to all link this rule, classes are made for this.

Example
insert a class inside css

```
.not-underline{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

update your html adding a class to your link

```
 <a href="#" class="not-underline>
  <div class="promo-box promo-1">
    <div class="promo-content">
     <h2>Heading here</h2>
     <p>Text content here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv4kn/1/)

Comment: I understand that - but that applies to all links on the site. i want to ONLY target the links in this box. the h2 AND the P.

Comment: apply a class to the link and use the class selector inside css is a good way to style your link not all link @lowercase

Comment: i understand, but any attempt to target those directly fails. i am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: no you can't style h2 and p without text-decoration because is inside a link @lowercase

Comment: ok. so I want every link on my site to be underlined EXCEPT the h2 and p in the example above. How do I target just those in css. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: thanks. that worked - gave the 'a' link a class of its own to target.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parent selector name before anchor tag  in CSS.

```
<div class='display'>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="promo-box promo-1">
      <div class="promo-content">
        <h2>Heading here</h2>
        <p>Text content here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display a{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sagarawasthi/N2m6e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

And to avoid text underlining on hover, add this to your css:

```
a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  }
```